# catching external links before redirecting user

Tags: php, function, preg-replace

i need to make my users aware that they are clicking an external link. I have many sorts of chats on my website and sometimes users post links, these links could be dangerous for them so i wanted to warn them before leaving the site.

For example eveonline.com uses the following on their forums: http://www.eveonline.com/externalLink.aspx?l=http://altdevblogaday.com/2011/07/11/the-hidden-evil-of-the-micro-transaction/

whenever a link shows up they see if the domain is different than eveonline.com and if it is they add the "http://www.eveonline.com/externalLink.aspx?l=" to it.

This is my makeClickableLinks function, i use it to make links clickable, i was wondering if someone could rewrite if for me to do the above + clickable as i didnt write this function since i am clueless with preg_match.

```
function makeClickableLinks($text)
    {
    $text = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)','<a target="_blank" href="\\1">\\1</a>', $text);

    $text = eregi_replace('([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)','\\1<a target="_blank" href="http://\\2">\\2</a>', $text);


    return $text;
    }
```

the variable $text is the post of the user.

Comment: Learn regex, then preg_match = easy peasy.  Start here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no PHP wizard, but give this a try.  Note that almost all of this is taken straight out of the PHP manual [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

```
function makeClickableLinks($text)
{
    $text = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)',
                          '<a target="_blank" href="\\1">\\1</a>', $text);      

    $text = eregi_replace('([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)',
                          '\\1<a target="_blank" href="http://\\2">\\2</a>', 
                          $text);

    $regex = '@(<a.*?href=")((?!(?:(?:f|ht)tps?://)?(?:[a-z0-9]+\.)?domain\.com)[^"]*)@i';
    $replacement = '$1http://your.domain.com/externLink.php?l=$2';

    $text = preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $text);

    return $text;
}
```

Comment: thanks elmugrat, i think you missed the fact that $text is the user's post, it comes with text, some <br>s maybe and URLS without the "a" tag. Thats what my function is for, return the same text but adds the "a" tags to the URLS. I am trying to make that function see if the link is external and if so add my redirector. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah ok I did misunderstand that.  I'll edit my answer...check back in a few.

Comment: thanks mate, i am getting the warning Warning: eregi_replace() [function.eregi-replace]: REG_BADRPT in the 3rd eregi_replace line, wonder what that is...

Comment: *sigh* that's why I shouldn't answer questions when I'm 3/4 asleep... I edited it again  :)

Comment: hehe well it still gives REG_BADRPT as soon as i call it on that last eregi :(

Comment: @JoanSilverstone let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1501/discussion-between-elmugrat-and-joan-silverstone)

Comment: its working mate, thanks :) you think you could change it so that it read for the domain.com and not www.domain.com only? because this way if people dont add the www or the links points to s ubdomain it counts as external. Great job, i am on chat if you wish :)